# ngRepeat on a <tr> with rowspan?

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table

A quick example like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
  <td rowspan="2">{{user.name}}<td>
  <td>foo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>{{user.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

How would something like that work in Angular? I've tried the above and it just doesn't work without messing up the layout. I've also tried wrapping the two `<tr>` with a `<span>` and it doesn't help either. Is this something out of `ng-repeat's` functionality?

EDIT: Keep it on HTML only, no use of JS code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Silly me, I should've read through the documentation more:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

Updated angular (needs to be > 1.16) so there's `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="user in users">
  <td rowspan="2">{{user.name}}<td>
  <td>foo</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end>
  <td>{{user.age}}</td>
</tr>
```